# Foundation 5 - Equalizer, height="inherit" issue

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I am using equalizer with a nested equalizer to make an article object with a nested `<h2>` object the same height in a grid layout.

So all `<article>` elements are the same height, and all `<h2>` elements within the articles are the same height.
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/equalizer.html

As long as the grid layout does not expand to a second line, everything works fine and equalizer does its thing.

[image: Image 1]

But the second the grid layout expands to a second line equalizer sets height to

> height="inherit"

And both `<article>` and `<h2>` (within the articles) elements lose their equal height.

[image: Image 2]

I have also tried to put the h2 element inside a div element and have `data-equalizer-watch="sub2"` on this, but gives same result.

```
<div id="siteContent" class="row" data-equalizer="sub1">
    <div data-equalizer="sub2">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns panel articleFrontpage" data-equalizer-watch="sub1">
            <a href="#">
                <article>
                    <time datetime="2015-12-31" pubdate="pubdate"></time>
                    <h2 data-equalizer-watch="sub2">Super long headline if u believe. Let the force guide you</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p>News category<span> <span>2015-12-31</span></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget quam interdum, elementum tellux asdasd asasdasdasda , elementum tellux asdasd asasdasdasda</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns panel articleFrontpage" data-equalizer-watch="sub1">
            <a href="#">
                <article>
                    <time datetime="2015-12-31" pubdate="pubdate"></time>
                    <h2 data-equalizer-watch="sub2">headline</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p>News category<span> <span>2015-12-31</span></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras eget quam interdum, elementum tellux asdasd asasdasdasda , elementum tellux asdasd asasdasdasda</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns panel articleFrontpage" data-equalizer-watch="sub1">
            <a href="#">
                <article>
                    <time datetime="2015-12-31" pubdate="pubdate"></time>
                    <h2 data-equalizer-watch="sub2">headline</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p>News category<span> <span>2015-12-31</span></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns panel articleFrontpage" data-equalizer-watch="sub1">
            <a href="#">
                <article>
                    <time datetime="2015-12-31" pubdate="pubdate"></time>
                    <h2 data-equalizer-watch="sub2">headline</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p>News category<span> <span>2015-12-31</span></p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: The images in your question are not loading (access denied). You need to save them and upload them somewhere else.

Comment: You should make a new row every time that you have reached the maximum number of columns for a row (12 by default). Right now, on large you have 16 columns and in medium you have 24 columns in one row.

Comment: I see your point. Than what do you do if you have three <div class="columns"> each taking up 4 columns places in large view, and when the user shrink his / her browser you want them to take more space like 6 columns?

Comment: Extension of above.
Also when you go to small view and want each <div class="columns"> to be 12 columns wide you each time break the design? Because they arent in their own row.

Comment: Try it so that the large columns add up to 12 per row. Small and medium can exceed that. If that doesn't work, please provide a live example on something like [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io) and I will have a look.

Comment: @ColinMarshall I cant get equalizer to work properly still, i put up a live example [equalizer live](http://mnrb.dk/equalizer/) any help is appreciated. Equalizer sets height="inherit" and when resizing the window it gets even more obvious than from the large view